# Multithreaded Debugger

Tags: c++, c, gdb, debugging, pthreads

GDB has severe issues when debugging with multiple threads (pthreads).
Are there any other good multi-threaded debuggers for C/C++ on *nix?

Comment: This should also be tagged 'gdb'.

Comment: I seem to having problem debugging a thread class that is instanctiated multiple times(SEGMENTATION FAULT).  Is it me or is it GDB's fault.  At run time I dont have any seg faults

Comment: You need to post a new question for something like that, Yan. Also, I suggest you provide a *lot* more information when/if you do so; you’ve provided no useful information to allow us to help you fix your problem.

Answer (score 6):

I've personally not had any GDB specific issues when debugging a multi-threaded application, so it may helpful for you to elaborate on exactly what "issues" you are having. It will help us answer you better.

There are several aids that I have used in the past when debugging multi-threaded applications in linux, most of which build upon GDB rather than replace it. These include:

- DDD http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/
- Eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/
- Native POSIX Thread Library (NTPL) Trace Tool http://nptltracetool.sourceforge.net/

Additionally, if you are new to debugging in Linux (and even if you aren't!) I highly recommend the paper titled "Debugging Linux Applications" which you can find here:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/3009706/Debugging-Linux-Applications

Answer (score 5):

[Allinea DDT](http://www.allinea.com/products/ddt) ... graphical debugger for scalar, multi-threaded and large-scale parallel applications that are written in C, C++ and Fortran.

Answer (score 4):

[TotalView](http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview.aspx) is what the national labs use for huge clusters.  I believe it has some good support for thread parallelism, too.  It's probably out of your price range, but you can try it for free.

Answer (score 1):

From my search, I have not found any good multi-thread debuggers for *nix. GDB seems to be getting better, and the last time I had to debug a multi-threaded application on FreeBSD (7.0-RELEASE) it behaved fairly well, letting me find where the error was.

Answer (score 0):

I once looked for a gdb alternative, but unfortunately every one I found was based on gdb.  I think this is because gdb is intricately tied to gcc, and it's hard for third-party debuggers to keep up with every gcc change.

Answer (score 0):

The AIX debugger for windows, let's you debug multithread applications.