# Segmentation fault in multithreaded application

Tags: c++, pthreads, usleep

I have a Segmentation fault in my multithreaded application that is becoming a headache. It looks like the problem is being generated in a *usleep* call. I tried to replace it with *nanosleep* but it persists. It also appears near to a sem_timedwait call.

I compile with gcc and -lpthread option.

Might this be the cause of the segmentation fault? What could be the reason?

Comment: More likely that the root of the segmentation fault is an error in your code. Until you show your code, it's imposible to say what's wrong.

Comment: This question doesn't really fit the SO question/answer format.  Try coming up with a more specific question.

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, you need to post a MINIMAL COMPLETE example.  It needs to be small so it fits in a post, but also needs to be complete, showing everything necessary to reproduce the problem.  Without that, you won't get any useful help.

Comment: I'd like to post the problematic code, but the application is huge and multithreaded and I cannot locate it. I work with an embedded device and I have no possibility to make real-time debugging :(  Just wanted to know if usleep/nanosleep/sem_timedwait is a possibility...

Comment: @mydog Whilst a specific answer cannot be given, general guidance can be offered. Indeed the Q asks for just that. Sometimes you need to tailor the response to the level of detail available in the Q.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There are lots of better ways to get a more detailed answer to that question than asking a new one on SO including simply finding old questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718998/methodology-for-fixing-segmentation-faults-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77522/multithreaded-debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segmentation fault means that you are accessing memory which you don't have rights to. It is usually due to a bounds error on an array or a stale pointer, e.g. access after free. Calling sleep seems exceedingly unlikely to be related to this unless you are using sleep as a synchronization tool! You could use valgrind to track down your error.